# For integers from 1 to 4n-1,pick two integers and replace them with their difference.For n=1 we have 1,2,3 if we pick 1,3 our new numbers will be 2,2…

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

For integers from $1$ to $4n-1$, we pick two integers and replace them with their difference. That is for $n=1$ we have $1,2,3$ if we pick $1,3$ our new numbers will be $2,2$. Show that at $4n-2$ step the remaining number would be even. This is a question from a local mathematical contest, I couldn't figure out the solution. Thanks for any help!

Comment: *replace them by there difference*, no plural you mean right?

Comment: Help me understand this: Let's say we set $n = 3$, and let's also say that from 1 to 11 we pick 3 and 8. What do we replace 3 and 8 with? And after we do that replacement, how does the process continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We rephrase the problem in order to make it more explicit. At the beginning, we have the numbers $1$ to $4n-1$ written on a blackboard. At every step, we take two of the numbers on the blackboard, say $a$ and $b$, erase them, and write $a-b$, or perhaps $|a-b|$, on the blackboard. So after $4n-2$ steps, there will be only $1$ number on the blackboard. Show this number must be even.

---

Consider the **parity** of the sum. At the beginning, the sum of the numbers on the board is $1+2+\cdots+(4n-1)$. This is even. That can be seen by noting that the sum is $\frac{(4n-1)(4n)}{2}$, and in other ways.

When we replace the two numbers $a$ and $b$ by the single number $a-b$, or $|a-b|$, the parity of the sum does not change. This is because $a-b$ has the same parity as $a+b$. (They are both even or both odd.) So since the sum started out even, the sum remains even. That means that when we are down to a single number, that number must be even.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ The operation preserves the fact that the list contains an even number of odd integers. Therefore, when you reach a list of one element $\,k,\,$ the list has has zero odds, so $\,k\,$ is even.